# How to get distinct records in the quickviewer?

Tags: abap

I would like to get distinct record values as a result in the quickviewer.  Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly you cant. Since any Quickviewer SQVI Query can be converted into an SE11 Query and even therein no DISTINCT selects are allowed, Quickviewer is not allowed to neither.
In pure ABAP you can do a SELECT DISTINCT (OpenSQL), but unfortunatelly not in QuickViewer.

Comment: Not the answer I hoped for, but since I asume it's correct, tx.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer** (I would comment, but i can't, yet).

Do you mean distinct records from a single db table? 
Since queries query a db table, which presumably has unique keys, the only thing to do is enforcing as input to the query all the required keys.

Or do you mean fields of different records having different (distinct) values? I haven't tried that, but what about injecting some extra code, from transaction SQ02, and deleting/collecting rows based on your criteria, thus ensuring distinct non-key fields in your records.